# Yii2 query using not condition

Tags: php, yii2

I have this query in yii2

```
return static::find()->where(['truck_status' => 1])
        ->all();
```

Now i would like to use a not condition that is

```
return static::find()->where(['truck_status' !=> 1]) //this fails
        ->all();
```

But it fails

How do i go about this

Comment: Hint: When something is _not_ "greater than _or_ equal" it can be only one other thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coud use operator notation

```
     return static::find()->where(['<>' , 'truck_status',1]) 
    ->all();
```

this could be useful  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html *take a look at the where section*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a condition in **Operator Format**.

```
return static::find()
    ->where(['not', ['truck_status' => 1]]) 
    ->all();
```

Basically here you have `[$operator, $operand1, $operand2]` where the operator must be a string like 'between', 'like', etc.

The operands depend on the operator you are using, so you should check the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail).

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this :

```
return static::find()->where(['!=','truck_status','1'])->all();
```